# PHP - call __invoke with a variable number of arguments

Tags: php, variadic-functions

Is it possible, with some kind of dirty trick possibly, to invoke a class via the `__invoke` magic method using a variable number of arguments?

I know that in php 5.6 there are variadics, but my version is not there yet...

For a normal class method I could try to do something using the magic method `__call` and the `call_user_func_array` function. What about the `__invoke` magic method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be possible with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

Adjusting the [example from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke):

```
<?php
class CallableClass
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }
}
$obj = new CallableClass;
$obj(5, 6, 7, 8); // vary arguments to meet your needs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest operator:

```
public function __invoke(...$args)
{
    print_r($args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't seem to mind if you add the arguments to the invoke method.

So this would also work:

```
<?php

class Invoked
{
    public function __invoke($value, $key)
    {
        var_dump($value, $key);
    }
}

$numbers = range(0, 10);

array_walk($numbers, new Invoked);
```